# Is there a way to use libgit2-glib on Vala?

Tags: compiler-errors, vala, libgit2

This is my minimal reproducible example: **Test.vala**

```
using Ggit;

class Test : GLib.Object {

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        File repositoryFile = File.new_for_path("./");
        Repository repository = Repository.open(repositoryFile);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If I compile the program with `valac --pkg libgit2-glib-1.0 Test.vala` I get:

```
error: Package `libgit2-glib-1.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
```

If I use instead `valac --pkg ggit-1.0 Test.vala` I get

```
fatal error: libgit2-glib/ggit.h: No such file or directory
#include <libgit2-glib/ggit.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
```

Both **libgit2-glib-1.0-0** and **libgit2-glib-1.0-dev** are installed and the location of the file that it says it's missing is: **`/usr/include/libgit2-glib-1.0/libgit2-glib/ggit.h`**

If I use

```
valac --pkg ggit-1.0 --Xcc="-I/usr/include/libgit2-glib-1.0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs libgit2-glib-1.0`" Test.vala
```

I get the same error as above.

Whereas if I use `valac --pkg ggit-1.0 --Xcc="-I/usr/include/libgit2-glib-1.0" Test.vala` it can find the headers properly, but then it complains that it cannot link it:

```
/tmp/ccSjHLvX.o: In function `test_main':
Test.vala.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `ggit_repository_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: cc exited with status 256
```

Is there any way to use **libgit2-glib** on vala?

**Edit**:

If I do:

```
valac --pkg ggit-1.0 Test.vala -C
gcc Test.c -o Test `pkg-config --cflags --libs libgit2-glib-1.0`
```

It compiles well. But I wonder if it is possible to do it in one single command with **valac** rather than having to call valac to generate the sources and then manually calling **gcc** to compile.

Comment: I had a look at https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libgit2-glib-1.0-dev/filelist and /usr/share/vala/vapi/libgit2-glib-1.0.vapi is there. Are you compiling in a sandboxed environment like GNOME Builder?

Comment: I am not sure if I am in a sandboxed environment. Here is a screenshot of the library installed from Synaptic Package manager and the vapi files it puts in on installation: https://postimg.cc/QHPzqHG9. And here is a list given by Synaptic of all the installed files for the package: https://pastebin.com/5ZH6FkiW. Synaptic says that the version I have installed is 0.26.2-1. I don't know if that might be why.

Comment: That looks like to be the problem. Ubuntu bionic doesn't have that version of the library: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgit2-glib-1.0-dev/filelist
It has an old version. I don't know how to install a newer version though.